# Pagination for the records in angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I need only 10 records per page and there are total 80 records.
How do I get it

below is the sample data i am getting from api,there are 79 more like this.

```
Array(80)
```

```
0:
description: null
groups: null
name: "Vz Vendor Work Portal"
projects: null
subdomain: null
vast_id: 25589
vsad: "h2rv",
```

I am using bootstrap for pagination.

```
 <ul class="pagination">
<li class="disabled"><a class="paginate first" href="">First</a></li>
<li class="hidden-xs"><a class="paginate previous" href="">Previous</a></li>
<li><a href="">1</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="">2</a></li>
<li><a href="">3</a></li>
<li class="hidden-xs"><a href="">4</a></li>
<li class="hidden-xs"><a href="">5</a></li>
<li class="hidden-xs"><a class="paginate next" href="">Next</a></li>
<li><a class="paginate last" href="">Last</a></li>
```

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
          
               <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <ul class="col-md-12 list-none">
                   <div *ngFor="let app of appslist;">
                        <li class="col-md-4">
                        <div style="border: 1px;background-color: #EEEFED">
                               <span><b>{{app.name}}</b></span><br/>
                                <span>description goes here description goes here description goes here description goes here</span>
                                <br/>
                                <br/>
                                <span><a href="/radar/{{app.vsad}}">{{app.vsad}}</a></span>
                        </div>
                </li>
                </div>
                 </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
          
           
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: The problem might be related on backend. Perhaps you're not limiting to 10 records

Comment: I you are using tables, you might want to think about a datatable with it's huge range of options, including pagination. https://datatables.net/reference/option/

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution is to Paginate from your backend. but you can also use frontend if you are looking for just to show 10 records and not considering the performance.

You can use javascript `splice` function to archive this.

> array.splice((page-1)*recordsPerPage,recordsPerPage)

StackBlitz example can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b1qjxu?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: check the stackblitz i only added the function for page numbers.

Comment: No this doesn't work. I am displaying all the data in single page using card layout. I need only 10 cards to be displayed per page.